# Pandas Dataframe Row have unusual pattren of alphabet in rows and between the string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I am Talha and new to the Data science community. Today I worked on a data set and found something challenging to resolve this my data set
[image: dataset image]

there is a pattern of string that contains the ***"????"***. I am trying to remove them by comparison and isnull method but that does not work. also, this string appears in between the name as well and I don`t know how to deal with that can any help me?

> Blockquote

Comment: TBH looks like encoding issue.

Comment: yep! when I try to load data as encoding='utf-8' it's not working then someone says that you are using window then you change the format 'utf-8' to 'cp1252'.  and this trick works but now I am facing this issue!